# How to avoid "use db_name" each time I start mysql

Tags: mysql

Every time I start mysql, first query that I type is "use my_db_name" where my_db_name is the name of the database that I always use. I would like mysql to use my_db_name by default. Is there a way we can do that?

EDIT: I am connecting to mysql from command line.

Comment: How are you connecting to mysql?

Comment: Hi Darin, I am connecting to mysql from command line.

Comment: you can define the database name while connecting to server

Comment: while connecting to mysql you can pass the name of database as an argument i think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the options file (on windows my.ini, on linux my.cnf), in the Client section add the following:

```
database=db_name
```

Comment: Cool. That's what I was looking for. We need to put this directive in [mysql] section.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword databasename
```

Comment: Ok. That is useful. However, I don't type "-uuser -ppassword" part since I have put username/password in /etc/my.conf. So, "mysql databasename" does the job for me. Further I can alias "mysql" to "mysql databasename" and then just happily type "mysql" on console.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the database when connecting:

```
mysql --user=root --password=secret --database=my_db_name
```

or directly:

```
mysql my_db_name
```